# What is the power series for $f(x) = x^3e^{-x} + \sin(2x)$ centered at $x=0$?

Tags: calculus

What is the power series for $f(x) = x^3e^{-x} + \sin(2x)$ centered at $x=0$?

I am unsure how to find the power series when the function is in this form.

Comment: Can you do $x^3e^{-x}$? And $\sin 2x$?

Comment: I think as long as you can take derivatives you can get the power series right?

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Let $e^{-x} = \sum a_n x^n$ and $\sin(2x) = \sum b_n x^n$. Then
$$
f(x) = x^3 e^{-x} + \sin(2x)
     = \sum a_n x^{n+3} + \sum b_n x^n
     = \sum_{n \ge 3} a_{n-3} x^n + \sum b_n x^n
$$
Can you finish this?

Comment: I guess I am still a little confused. Would I use the general formulas like e^x = ∑(x^n)/n! ?

Comment: @SaarahMaxon yes, you have to find $a_n$ and $b_n$